# Open/Close principle and polymorphism

Tags: oop

The Open/Closed Principle states that software entities (classes, modules, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification. I learned about this today and my teacher said that this concept is intrinsically connected to the concept of polymorphism. I can´t really see how both concepts are connected, can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's my exaplanation.
Look at the following example:

```cs
public interface IShape
{
    void Draw();
}

public class Square : IShape
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        // DRAW SQUARE
    }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        // DRAW CIRCLE
    }
}

public class Renderer
{
    public void DrawShapes(ICollection<IShape> shapes)
    {
        foreach (var shape in shapes)
        {
            shape.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is open to extensions and closed to modifications therefore it follows the OCP principle. Why? In case you need to make the application able to draw a new shape (e.g. Triangle), you don't need to modify the *DrawShapes* method of the *Render* class.
You only need to create a new class "Triangle" that implements the interface *IShape* and pass it to the *DrawShapes* method.
This code is also polymorphic because the "DrawShapes" method does not need to know the types of the shapes that it is rendering.

Pay attention to one thing: the closure of the O.C.P. principle is always **strategic**. What does it mean? It means that you cannot have code that is 100% closed to modifications. Example: what happens if you need to draw all the squares before the circles? In that case you have to modify the *DrawShapes* method; maybe with a Strategy pattern you can inject the policy to sort the drawing of the shapes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood the idea!